# Referencing a MYSQL Result Set without looping

Tags: mysql, arrays, set, associative

I have a small result set from a MySQL query, comprising 4 records.

I have converted it into an associative array where in each row has 3 columns:

```
id, field_1, field_2
```

The ids are 1, 2, 3, and 4, and I want to reference field_1 with `id = 2`.

How would I reference that?

Like this?

`$row[2]['field_1']`

I know I should be able to work this out but I just cant get my head around it for some reason :-)  Maybe I am having a stroke or an embolism :-)

I don't need to loop through it cause I know where everything is :-)

Comment: Unless you convert the array to json (and thereby use js methods to grab the data), I think you're obliged to parse the array in some manner (e.g. with a loop)

Answer (score 0):

If your array `$row` isn't indexed by the column `id` and the rows are ordered ascending by `id` then you should use `$row[1]['field_1']` as arrays start with index 0, so the index `2` is actually 3rd row (`id = 3`).

But the best way to figure out is to print out the array after you get it,

```
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>'; die();
```

Which will print a formatted array for you with all the indexes and their values, so you can see what you can reference from where.